# get Parent entity based on child

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

I'm trying to get the parent entity based on child object: 
I have entity Parent like:

```
public Class Parent{
...
@ManyToOne
private Child child;
 //getters & setters
   }
```

when I use this method to get the parents with a specific child like:

```
public ArrayList<Parent>getParentsByChild(Child child){
 String req="from Parent p where p.child= :child";
Query query = em.createQuery(req, Parent.class);
query.setParameter("child", child);
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Parent> parents= (ArrayList<Parent>)  query.getResultList();
    return parents;
}
```

I get the exception of invalid identifier, question is can I even get the parents list with a pecific child, if yes, what do I have to change in the query.

thanks for your help,

Comment: try to add the stacktrace. Also add how are parent and child related on the database level.

Comment: Also, don't cast to ArrayList. You get a List back, use that List. Casting to ArrayList will just make your code crash if Hibernate decides to use another List implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query in your code.

```
String hql = "select p from Parent p where p.child = :child"
```